# If $f(x)$ is a polynomial function with integer coefficients find min value of $f(12)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> $f(x)$ is a polynomial function with integer coefficients satisfying $f(1)=5$ and $f(2)=7$. What is the smallest possible positive value of $f(12)$?

I have no idea on how to begin with this question. Also, I can't get any clue on the significance of integer coefficients.

Comment: Absent such a condition, there is no minimum since Lagrange Interpolation will give rational coefficients if $f(12)\in \mathbb Q$.  For instance, if you want $f(12)=-10^6$, we could have $\frac {-999862}{55} + \frac {3000301}{110 } x- \frac {1000027}{110}x^2$.

Comment: @lulu Edit: smallest possible positive value of $f(12)$

Comment: @lulu, integer coefficents is the keyword and it should be smallest positive value of f(12)

Comment: Ok, well you could still get $f(12)=1$ as $\frac {139}{55} + \frac {149}{55}x - \frac {13}{55}x^2$.

Comment: @lulu What about integer coefficients?

Comment: Hint: If $f(x)\in\Bbb{Z}[x]$ then $f(m)-f(n)$ is an integer multiple of $m-n$.

Comment: In your post, you asked what the significance of integer coefficients was.  My comments are intended to show that, absent such a condition, there is no restriction on $f(12)$ since Lagrange preserves rationality but not integrality.

Comment: @lulu Okay... thanks ;-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Can you please extend a bit, sir?

Comment: So $f(12)-f(2)$ must be a multiple of ten and $f(12)-f(1)$ is a multiple of eleven. I guess you are expected to set up the congruence system and solve it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen- How does that lead to the answer?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $f(12)=10k+7$ and $f(12)=11p+5$. The smallest integers $k,p$ for which this is true gives $f(12)=27$... for $k=p=2$. So, $27$ is the answer. Am I correct?

Comment: I am fairly sure that we have handled similar questions in the past. Did you search? Anyway, solving that system of congruences, Chinese remainder theorem style, will give you a set of possible values of $f(12)$. Pick the smallest positive one. Then construct a polynomial $f(x)$ achieving that.

Comment: Yes, Tatan. That is correct. Still, that congruence is only a necessary condition. Can you find a polynomial $f(x)$ such that $f(1), f(2)$ and $f(12)$ all have the prescribed value?

Comment: And... Do you see where that divisibility criterion comes from?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am not too confident with congruences. I don't know much of Chinese Remainder theorem

Comment: @tatan- But how could you say that f(12) will assume 27 for some value. You have to prove. For eg if it were given that f(5)=14 then what would you do.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen- 2x+3.

Comment: Correct, @LoveInvariants :-)

Comment: @LoveInvariants I used the facts that Jyrki sir said... that divisibility condition

Comment: @LoveInvariants How did you get that? You solved the system of congruences?

Comment: @tatan- yup, for this question, you can quote the polynomial 2x+3 easily with the solution but if it is too complicated. How would you prove that f(12) will assume certain value.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Can you provide a link or add an answer to explain in a bit more detai?

Comment: @tatan- I was solving for positive integral coefficients though :P. Subtracted both functions to get 2 as the coefficient of x.

Comment: Looking for one, but couldn't find a good one right away. I summoned Bill Dubuque, for IIRC he has explained it somewhere here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, looking forward to the solution ;-)

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/11619) help?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks. I need some time. I would definitely get back on this in some time ;-)

Comment: By any chance do you have the final answer to the question? I think the mininum to $f(12)$ is $5$.

Comment: @Dahaka Answer says its $27$ but I am ready to accept $5$ if its logical

Comment: Oh, I made a few mistakes anyway. Well, then here is a thought: Since $f(1)=5=2(1)+3$ and $f(2)=7=2(2)+3$ we have that $f(x) - (2x+3)$ has as roots $1 $ and $2 $, also the function is of the form: $$f(x) =g(x) (x-1)(x-2)+2x+3\rightarrow f(12)=g(12)\cdot 11\cdot 10+27$$ Where $g(x) $ is a random polynomial with integer coefficients and with atleast $2$ degree less than $f(x) $. Now we only need to show that the minimum of this polynomial $g(x) $ in $x=12$ is $0$ and we obtain that the minimum of $f(12)$ is $27$. I don't really know for the moment how to show that, hopefully someone can help.

Comment: @Dahaka: You are practically done; $g(12)$ is an integer, and so if it is negative you have an upper bound on it. No need to care about degree. The core structure of this proof is the same as Jryki's.